# Can Adobe AIR for desktop run a Stage 3D project?

Tags: air, adobe, stage3d

I am curious that if Flash Plahyer 11+ has ability to provide Stage 3D feature for web browser.

How about Adobe AIR 3.1? Does it support Stage 3D for building 3D game for desktop platform too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.

> Adobe Flash Player previously rendered thousands of non z-buffered triangles at approximately 30 Hz. With the new Stage3D APIs, you can expect hundreds of thousands of z-buffered triangles to be rendered at HD resolution in full screen at around 60 Hz. Using the new Stage3D APIs in Flash Player and **Adobe AIR** will make it possible to deliver sophisticated 3D experiences across almost every computer and device connected to the Internet.
>   http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html

Comment: You will need to add `-swf-version=13` to the compiler arguments and `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>` to the application.xml - this had me stumped for a while.